# Drag and Drop files to Firefox browser is working but not to Microsoft Edge in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: flatpak, drag-and-drop

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 and I've installed Microsoft Edge for Linux using flatpak. I am not able to drag and drop files to Edge browser from my Desktop or Files app. However, the drag and drop to the Mozilla Firefox browser is working perfectly. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

When Microsoft Edge (or any other application) is installed on Linux via Flatpak from Flathub, the application is **sandboxed**. This means it has **limited access to the system's files and directories by default**, which can cause issues like the one mentioned in the question with file access or drag-and-drop functionality. To resolve these issues, one typically needs to adjust the permissions of the Flatpak application to allow it broader access to your filesystem:

#### Granting Access to System Files for a Flatpak Application

You can use the `flatpak override` command to grant additional filesystem access to a specific Flatpak application. Here's a general approach on how to do it:

**Identify the Application ID**: First, you need to know the application ID of Microsoft Edge installed via Flatpak. You can find this with the command `flatpak list`.

1. After identifying the application ID, you can use the `flatpak override` command to grant access to specific directories. For example, to grant access to your entire home directory, you could use:

```sh
flatpak override --user --filesystem=home com.microsoft.Edge
```

(Replace `com.microsoft.Edge` with the actual application ID if it's a different application.)

2. If you only want to give access to specific directories, you can specify those instead of `home`. For example, to grant access to `/media` and `/mnt` (where external drives are often mounted), you could use:

```sh
flatpak override --user --filesystem=/media --filesystem=/mnt com.microsoft.Edge
```

After applying the override, you may need to restart Edge for the changes to take effect. Then, test to see if the issue with file access has been resolved.

#### Important Considerations

- **Security Implications**: Broadening filesystem access for sandboxed applications increases their potential attack surface. Only grant permissions as much access as necessary for the application to function.
- **Persistence**: Overrides applied with `flatpak override` are persistent across reboots until you explicitly remove them.
- **Removing Overrides**: If you wish to remove the overrides and revert to the default sandbox permissions, you can use the `--reset` option with the `flatpak override` command, specifying the application ID.
- **Documentation and Help**: For more detailed information about managing Flatpak permissions and overrides, consult the Flatpak documentation or use `flatpak override --help` to see all available options.